# nvd3 - Rescale Y axis and show Outlier Data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, charts, nvd3.js

I am creating a lineChart with NVD3 that is currently plotting my points correctly. The default behavior of the Y axis automatically scales the ticks on the Y axis. Then when a series is selected or deselected, the Y axis automatically resizes according to the present series.

There are two problems with this:

1. When the resizing happens, the Y axis flips, making the values decrease as you move up the Y axis.
2. *More importantl*y, the automatic initial Y axis scale dramatically underestimates the Y axis values, causing many data points (outliers) to not be shown in the visual.

I have played around with ***Ydomain and forceY*** to set the min and max values of my data on the Y axis, *but then I lose the functionality of the auto-scaling when selecting or deselecting a series*.

I would like to have my visual preserve the default behavior of auto-scaling the Y axis when selecting and deselecting series, but also have it not cut the Y axis off early, thus showing all outlier data points.

Any help is much appreciated.

Current JS code:

```
d3.json('..\\static\\data\\hydrograph_data.json', function(data) {  // open more dynamic file path

  nv.addGraph( function() {

    var getX = function(d) { return d.time_mili }
    var getY = function(d) { return d.value }
    var getMax = function(d) { return d.max }

    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values, getY)})
    var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, getMax)})

    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                  .x( getX )  // this value is stored in miliseconds since epoch (converted in data_format.py with datetime)
                  .y( getY ) 
                  .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                  //.yDomain([min, max])
                  .margin({left: 90})
                  // .showControls(false)
                  ;

    chart.xAxis
        .axisLabel(" Date ")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%y-%d-%m')(new Date(d))
        });

    chart.yAxis
        //.axisLabel('Discharge (cubic feet per second)')
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(",")(d) + " cfps"});

    d3.select('#hydrograph svg')
        .datum(data)
        .call(chart);

    //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
  });

});
```

**p.s.**

I am working on a fiddle, but a sample of my data in the fiddle does not produce the same problems, so it is difficult to recreate without the entire data file present, which I cannot do in jsfiddle.

**edit:**

temporary solution was to create a dummy value point at the start of the series with value 0 as seen in NatasaPeic's answer to the [issue](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/695).

Comment: do you want to hard code y-axis?